# Cant iterate through the array of fetched records

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, api, asynchronous

I have a script that fetches data from an API. I have 2 .then functions, one for parsing the function in a json and another for pushing the data into an array. But after that I can't loop over the values or access them whatsoever. I saw this question asked multiple times but none of the answers worked.
Here s the code :

```
fetch(`${api_url}/${table_name}`)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        for(let row of data){
        response.push(row);
        }
    });
```

, where response is an empty array.
So, how can I iterate through, aceess and modify the result array? 
Thanks in advance(Im losing my mind)

Comment: "_So, how can I iterate through_" you are already iterating through `data` array here. What is the issue here?

Comment: "_modify the result array_" There is no `result` array in your code only `data` and `response`. Please explain what errors are you getting while accessing and modifying them in your main post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Sorry, I meant how do I iterate and access elements of response.

Comment: Ok, do you mean how you can access `response` outside `.then()` method?

Comment: Yes thats the problem i just cant figure out

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function in your then part. That callback function will parse your response and then you can iterate over response items. See example below.

```
_ajaxhelper.get(uri,
    (response) => { this.handleResponse(response); },
    (error) => { this.handleFailure(error); }));
```

handleResponse function:

```
private handleResponse(response: any) {
var items = this.parseData(response);
//Iteration over items
 }
```